# Deducing $((\neg a \to \neg b) \to ((\neg a \to b) \to b)))$ from axioms

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, axioms

I have seen many questions here, using a different set of axioms than mine.

Here is mine :

$$1) (a \to (b \to a))$$
$$2) ((a \to (b \to c)) \to ((a \to b) \to (a \to c)))$$
$$3) ((\neg b \to \neg a) \to (a \to b))$$

Is it possible to deduce the following from these: $((a \to b) \to ((\neg a \to b) \to b))$.

I couldn't find a proof myself or online.

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Your goal is **false** when $a$ is _true_ and $b$ is _false_, so it had better not be derivable! Perhaps you were intending to prove $$ (\neg a\to \neg b)\to((\neg a \to b)\to a)$$ instead?

Comment: I have edited the aim. It's what many people also call The Theorem of contradiction that I'm trying to prove.

Comment: A couple of your logical statements have unmatched parentheses

Comment: Axioms 1 and 2 are the types for the $K$ and $S$ combinator.  This type of proof is basically an exercise in typed lambda calculus, doing it by hand is really not practical, nor how the axioms are intended to be used.  You want to find an algorithm for the "**type inhabitation problem**" , one that includes negation.  I believe doug spoonwoods answer does this using the prover9 algorithm.  Looking at the length of the answer, you'll see why no one would do this by hand.

Comment: Besides axioms you will need rules of deduction.  Otherwise those three axioms are the only things that can be proved.

Comment: @GEdgar It is conventional with this type of system to only have modus ponens as an inference rule.  The axioms themselves come from simple type theory of lambda calculus, and modus ponens is the translation of function application of typed lambda calculus.

Answer (score 1):

Undoubtedly a shorter proof exists, but here's a Prover9 proof:

% -------- Comments from original proof --------

% Proof 1 at 208.84 (+ 24.69) seconds.

% Length of proof is 53.

% Level of proof is 20.

% Maximum clause weight is 24.

% Given clauses 9783.

1 P((x -> y) -> ((-x -> y) -> y)) # label(non_clause) # label(goal).  [goal].

2 -P(x -> y) | -P(x) | P(y).  [assumption].

3 P(x -> (y -> x)).  [assumption].

4 P((x -> (y -> z)) -> ((x -> y) -> (x -> z))).  [assumption].

5 P((-x -> -y) -> (y -> x)).  [assumption].

6 -P((c1 -> c2) -> ((-c1 -> c2) -> c2)).  [deny(1)].

7 P(x -> (y -> (z -> y))).  [hyper(2,a,3,a,b,3,a)].

8 P(((x -> (y -> z)) -> (x -> y)) -> ((x -> (y -> z)) -> (x -> z))).  [hyper(2,a,4,a,b,4,a)].

9 P(x -> ((y -> (z -> u)) -> ((y -> z) -> (y -> u)))).  [hyper(2,a,3,a,b,4,a)].

10 P((x -> y) -> (x -> x)).  [hyper(2,a,4,a,b,3,a)].

11 P(((-x -> -y) -> y) -> ((-x -> -y) -> x)).  [hyper(2,a,4,a,b,5,a)].

12 P(x -> ((-y -> -z) -> (z -> y))).  [hyper(2,a,3,a,b,5,a)].

14 P(x -> (y -> (z -> (u -> z)))).  [hyper(2,a,3,a,b,7,a)].

17 P(x -> x).  [hyper(2,a,10,a,b,7,a)].

18 P(((x -> y) -> x) -> ((x -> y) -> y)).  [hyper(2,a,4,a,b,17,a)].

26 P((x -> ((y -> x) -> z)) -> (x -> z)).  [hyper(2,a,8,a,b,7,a)].

44 P((x -> ((y -> (z -> y)) -> u)) -> (x -> u)).  [hyper(2,a,8,a,b,14,a)].

48 P(((x -> (y -> z)) -> (((x -> y) -> (x -> z)) -> u)) -> ((x -> (y -> z)) -> u)).  [hyper(2,a,8,a,b,9,a)].

71 P((x -> (-y -> -z)) -> (x -> (z -> y))).  [hyper(2,a,4,a,b,12,a)].

159 P(-x -> (x -> y)).  [hyper(2,a,26,a,b,12,a)].

160 P((x -> y) -> ((z -> x) -> (z -> y))).  [hyper(2,a,26,a,b,9,a)].

166 P(x -> (-y -> (y -> z))).  [hyper(2,a,3,a,b,159,a)].

197 P(((-x -> (x -> y)) -> z) -> z).  [hyper(2,a,18,a,b,166,a)].

815 P(((x -> y) -> z) -> (y -> z)).  [hyper(2,a,44,a,b,160,a)].

835 P(x -> (((y -> z) -> u) -> (z -> u))).  [hyper(2,a,3,a,b,815,a)].

841 P(x -> ((x -> y) -> y)).  [hyper(2,a,815,a,b,18,a)].

842 P(x -> ((-y -> -x) -> y)).  [hyper(2,a,815,a,b,11,a)].

915 P(((x -> ((x -> y) -> y)) -> z) -> z).  [hyper(2,a,841,a,b,841,a)].

918 P((x -> y) -> (x -> ((y -> z) -> z))).  [hyper(2,a,160,a,b,841,a)].

1299 P((x -> (-y -> -x)) -> (x -> y)).  [hyper(2,a,4,a,b,842,a)].

3180 P((x -> (y -> z)) -> (y -> (x -> z))).  [hyper(2,a,48,a,b,835,a)].

3224 P(x -> ((((x -> y) -> y) -> z) -> z)).  [hyper(2,a,915,a,b,918,a)].

4594 P(--x -> x).  [hyper(2,a,197,a,b,1299,a)].

4644 P(--x -> ((x -> y) -> y)).  [hyper(2,a,918,a,b,4594,a)].

4672 P(x -> --x).  [hyper(2,a,5,a,b,4594,a)].

4728 P((x -> y) -> (x -> --y)).  [hyper(2,a,160,a,b,4672,a)].

7577 P((-x -> y) -> (-y -> x)).  [hyper(2,a,71,a,b,4728,a)].

19603 P(x -> ((x -> y) -> --y)).  [hyper(2,a,3180,a,b,4728,a)].

19609 P((x -> y) -> (--x -> y)).  [hyper(2,a,3180,a,b,4644,a)].

19633 P((x -> y) -> ((y -> z) -> (x -> z))).  [hyper(2,a,3180,a,b,160,a)].

20528 P(--x -> ((x -> y) -> --y)).  [hyper(2,a,19609,a,b,19603,a)].

23007 P((((x -> y) -> y) -> z) -> (x -> z)).  [hyper(2,a,3180,a,b,3224,a)].

25963 P(((--x -> y) -> z) -> ((x -> y) -> z)).  [hyper(2,a,19633,a,b,19609,a)].

26004 P(((-x -> y) -> z) -> ((-y -> x) -> z)).  [hyper(2,a,19633,a,b,7577,a)].

26321 P((x -> y) -> (--x -> --y)).  [hyper(2,a,3180,a,b,20528,a)].

27746 P((x -> y) -> (-y -> -x)).  [hyper(2,a,71,a,b,26321,a)].

27754 P(x -> (-y -> -(x -> y))).  [hyper(2,a,23007,a,b,27746,a)].

28030 P(-x -> (y -> -(y -> x))).  [hyper(2,a,3180,a,b,27754,a)].

28135 P((-x -> y) -> (-x -> -(y -> x))).  [hyper(2,a,4,a,b,28030,a)].

29738 P((-x -> y) -> ((y -> x) -> x)).  [hyper(2,a,71,a,b,28135,a)].

34389 P((-x -> y) -> ((x -> y) -> y)).  [hyper(2,a,26004,a,b,29738,a)].

34398 P((x -> y) -> ((-x -> y) -> y)).  [hyper(2,a,25963,a,b,34389,a)].

34399 $F.  [resolve(34398,a,6,a)].

Edit: Here's a shorter proof via OTTER.  OTTER has found shorter proofs also, but they took more time for OTTER to find.

----> UNIT CONFLICT at   2.23 sec ----> 8034 [binary,8033.1,2.1] $F.

Length of proof is 36.  Level of proof is 18.

---------------- PROOF ----------------

1 [] -P(C(x,y))| -P(x)|P(y).

2 [] -P(C(C(a,b),C(C(N(a),b),b))).

3 [] P(C(x,C(y,x))).

4 [] P(C(C(x,C(y,z)),C(C(x,y),C(x,z)))).

5 [] P(C(C(N(x),N(y)),C(y,x))).

6 [hyper,1,3,3] P(C(x,C(y,C(z,y)))).

7 [hyper,1,3,4] P(C(x,C(C(y,C(z,u)),C(C(y,z),C(y,u))))).

8 [hyper,1,4,3] P(C(C(x,y),C(x,x))).

9 [hyper,1,3,5] P(C(x,C(C(N(y),N(z)),C(z,y)))).

10 [hyper,1,4,6] P(C(C(x,y),C(x,C(z,y)))).

15 [hyper,1,8,3] P(C(x,x)).

16 [hyper,1,4,15] P(C(C(C(x,y),x),C(C(x,y),y))).

21 [hyper,1,3,10] P(C(x,C(C(y,z),C(y,C(u,z))))).

23 [hyper,1,10,4] P(C(C(x,C(y,z)),C(u,C(C(x,y),C(x,z))))).

35 [hyper,1,3,16] P(C(x,C(C(C(y,z),y),C(C(y,z),z)))).

39 [hyper,1,16,6] P(C(C(C(x,C(y,x)),z),z)).

58 [hyper,1,4,21] P(C(C(x,C(y,z)),C(x,C(y,C(u,z))))).

74 [hyper,1,3,39] P(C(x,C(C(C(y,C(z,y)),u),u))).

136 [hyper,1,4,74] P(C(C(x,C(C(y,C(z,y)),u)),C(x,u))).

191 [hyper,1,136,5] P(C(C(N(x),N(C(y,C(z,y)))),x)).

192 [hyper,1,136,4] P(C(C(x,C(C(y,x),z)),C(x,z))).

199 [hyper,1,192,35] P(C(x,C(C(x,y),y))).

200 [hyper,1,192,9] P(C(N(x),C(x,y))).

201 [hyper,1,192,7] P(C(C(x,y),C(C(z,x),C(z,y)))).

215 [hyper,1,4,200] P(C(C(N(x),x),C(N(x),y))).

216 [hyper,1,3,200] P(C(x,C(N(y),C(y,z)))).

230 [hyper,1,3,215] P(C(x,C(C(N(y),y),C(N(y),z)))).

258 [hyper,1,3,199] P(C(x,C(y,C(C(y,z),z)))).

271 [hyper,1,23,201] P(C(x,C(C(C(y,z),C(u,y)),C(C(y,z),C(u,z))))).

274 [hyper,1,4,201] P(C(C(C(x,y),C(z,x)),C(C(x,y),C(z,y)))).

1921 [hyper,1,192,271] P(C(C(x,y),C(C(y,z),C(x,z)))).

2066 [hyper,1,274,258] P(C(C(C(C(x,y),y),z),C(x,z))).

2070 [hyper,1,274,230] P(C(C(C(N(x),y),z),C(C(N(x),x),z))).

2072 [hyper,1,274,216] P(C(C(C(x,y),z),C(N(x),z))).

2197 [hyper,1,2070,191] P(C(C(N(x),x),x)).

2204 [hyper,1,201,2197] P(C(C(x,C(N(y),y)),C(x,y))).

7657 [hyper,1,2204,2066] P(C(C(C(C(N(x),y),y),x),x)).

7700 [hyper,1,2072,7657] P(C(N(C(C(N(x),y),y)),x)).

7727 [hyper,1,1921,7700] P(C(C(x,y),C(N(C(C(N(x),z),z)),y))).

7831 [hyper,1,58,7727] P(C(C(x,y),C(N(C(C(N(x),z),z)),C(u,y)))).

8033 [hyper,1,2204,7831] P(C(C(x,y),C(C(N(x),y),y))).

8034 [binary,8033.1,2.1] $F.

------------ end of proof -------------

Comment: Why do you believe a shorter proof exists?

Comment: @DanielV Just experience with axiomatic systems.

Answer (score 0):

I have a fairly simple proof which when fully expanded is likely to be longer than [the proofs found by Prover9 and Otter](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1801040/234337).

Beyond making use of the deduction theorem, it requires the following three lemmas (I give the lengths of the proofs found by my own amateurish theorem prover):

1. 33 lines: $(\lnot x \to y) \to (\lnot y \to x)$
2. 7 lines: $(y \to z) \to (x \to y) \to (x \to z)$
3. 23 lines: $(\lnot x \to x) \to x$

**Proof**: assume $(\lnot a \to b)$ and $(a \to b)$. By $(\lnot a \to b)$ and lemma 1 $[a/x, b/y]$ conclude $(\lnot b \to a)$. By this and the assumption $(a \to b)$ plus lemma 2, conclude $(\lnot b \to b)$. By lemma 3, conclude $b$.

Convert this to an assumption-free proof of $(\lnot a \to b) \to (a \to b) \to b$ by applying the [deduction theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem#Conversion_from_proof_using_the_deduction_meta-theorem_to_axiomatic_proof) unwinding algorithm.

**Proof, now with more symbols and fewer words**:

1. $(\lnot a \to b), (a \to b) \vdash \lnot a \to b \quad$ [assumption]
2. $(\lnot a \to b), (a \to b) \vdash (\lnot a \to b) \to (\lnot b \to a) \quad$ [lemma 1]
3. $(\lnot a \to b), (a \to b) \vdash \lnot b \to a \quad$ [modus ponens, $2 \sim (1 \to 3)$]
4. $(\lnot a \to b), (a \to b) \vdash (a \to b) \to (\lnot b \to a) \to (\lnot b \to b) \quad$ [lemma 2]
5. $(\lnot a \to b), (a \to b) \vdash (a \to b) \quad$ [assumption]
6. $(\lnot a \to b), (a \to b) \vdash (\lnot b \to a) \to (\lnot b \to b) \quad$ [modus ponens, $4 \sim (5 \to 6)$]
7. $(\lnot a \to b), (a \to b) \vdash (\lnot b \to b) \quad$ [modus ponens, $6 \sim (3 \to 7)$]
8. $(\lnot a \to b), (a \to b) \vdash (\lnot b \to b) \to b \quad$ [lemma 3]
9. $(\lnot a \to b), (a \to b) \vdash b \quad$ [modus ponens, $8 \sim (7 \to 9)$]

Proofs of the lemmas are available on request.

Answer (score -1):

It helps to know:

- Two logical expressions are equivalent iff they have the same **truth table**
- $(a \rightarrow b) \leftrightarrow (\neg a \vee b) $ (One can proof that using the truth table)
- $(a \rightarrow b) \leftrightarrow (\neg b \rightarrow \neg a) $ (One can proof that using the truth table)
- $(a \vee \neg a) =1$ (Tautology)
- $\neg \neg a = a$ (Double negation)
- $1$ is the neutral element of the logical conjuction: $1\wedge a = a$

---

Here is my approach to deduce the given expression from elementary propositions:

Let $a$ and $b$ be two propositions, with 
$$a \rightarrow b$$
$$ \leftrightarrow \neg a \vee b$$ 
$$\leftrightarrow (\neg a \wedge b)\vee(\neg a \vee b)$$
$$\leftrightarrow (\neg (a \vee \neg b))\vee(\neg a \vee b)$$
$$\leftrightarrow (a \vee \neg b)\rightarrow (\neg a \vee b)$$
$$\leftrightarrow (a \vee \neg b)\rightarrow (b \vee \neg a)$$
$$\leftrightarrow (a \vee \neg b)\rightarrow (b \vee \neg a) \wedge 1 $$
$$\leftrightarrow (a \vee \neg b)\rightarrow (b \vee \neg a) \wedge (b \vee \neg b) $$
$$\leftrightarrow (a \vee \neg b)\rightarrow b \vee( \neg a \wedge \neg b) $$
$$\leftrightarrow (a \vee \neg b)\rightarrow b \vee \neg(a \vee b) $$
$$\leftrightarrow (a \vee \neg b)\rightarrow b \vee \neg(\neg \neg a \vee b) $$
$$\leftrightarrow (a \vee \neg b)\rightarrow b \vee \neg( \neg a \rightarrow b) $$
$$\leftrightarrow (a \vee \neg b)\rightarrow \neg( \neg a \rightarrow b) \vee b $$
$$\leftrightarrow (a \vee \neg b)\rightarrow (( \neg a \rightarrow b) \rightarrow b) $$
$$\leftrightarrow (\neg b \vee a)\rightarrow (( \neg a \rightarrow b) \rightarrow b) $$
$$\leftrightarrow (b \rightarrow a)\rightarrow (( \neg a \rightarrow b) \rightarrow b) $$
$$\leftrightarrow (\neg a \rightarrow \neg b)\rightarrow (( \neg a \rightarrow b) \rightarrow b)$$

Comment: You can only use detachment and substitution for this type of problem.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood When I learned mathematical logic, I did not hear(in the math lectures) nor read in mathematical books the suggested terms "Detachment" and "Substitution". But this does not mean that detachment and substitution are not mathematical concepts, which can be used to proof logical expressions. Well, my question is: What is the definition of detachment/substitution? Could you give an example of each concept? and the last question: Why are all ways closed except using  detachment and substitution?(You wrote I can use **only detachment and substitution**)

Comment: By 'detachment' I mean the rule of inference {($\alpha$ -> $\beta$), $\alpha$} $\vdash$ $\beta$.  By 'substitution' I mean that you can take all instances of a variable in a well-formed formed and substitute it with any other well-formed formula.  For example, in (p -> (q -> p)) you can substitute p with (p -> (q -> p)) and q with r.  Then you can detach (r -> (p -> (q -> p))).  The non-derived rules of inference for this system probably are detachment and substitution.